# What is the power supply connector used for?

Tags: power-supply, connector, atx

I recently came across an old ATX power supply, and one of its connectors looks like this (apologies for the quality):

[image: Power Supply Connector]

Does anybody know what this connector is called and what it connects to/is used for?

Comment: It connects to the motherboard. Nowadays there are far more pins. Don't know the name though, but I doubt this is actually ATX

Comment: Channel Well ATX-350, and it has all the connectors of a regular ATX power supply in addition to the one shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like one part of an AT-style PSU connector. There should be another one like it. These connect to older AT motherboards.

[image]

**EDIT**

OP commented that there is only one connector and that it is a Channel Well ATX-350 power supply. This is an ATX 6-pin auxiliary connector that was used on some older AMD motherboards.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for identifying the connector! What's bizarre is that the PSU only has a single AT connector, which I guess voids its purpose...

Comment: Does the connector have a regular 20 pin connection on the other end, [like this](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1pKbRHVXXXXbGXpXXq6xXFXXXq/20Pin-ATX-to-2-Port-6Pin-AT-PSU-Converter-Power-Cable-Cord-20cm-for-286-386.jpg)? Here is a bit of a [closer view](http://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g3-M01-4F-59-rBVaHFUBNXaAU25KAAKLq8V7X6A806.jpg/20pin-atx-to-2-port-6pin-at-psu-converter.jpg)

Comment: No, if you look closely, there are 2 rows, so the P8 and P9 are integrated into one plug.

Comment: In that case, since there's only one of them, it is an ATX 6-pin auxilary power cable. You should have the standard ATX mains connection as well. Some older AMD motherboards used this.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a 20Pin ATX to 2-Port 6Pin AT PSU power converter cable.

Comment: The power supply has an accompanying 24-pin power connector (no adapter), thought I'd mention that as well.